# Error converting data type varchar to bigint. in update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

while executing the following query:

```
declare @MaxSizeMB BIGINT
set @MaxSizeMB = 50

DECLARE @Query varchar(8000)='' 

set @Query = 'UPDATE SPMC
              SET SPMC.HasBlockedSize = 1, SPMC.HasIssues = 1
              FROM PWI
              INNER JOIN SI ON SI.Id = PWI.SourceItemId
              INNER JOIN SPMC ON SPMC.SourceItemId = SI.Id
                              AND SI.ItemSize > ' + CAST(@MaxSizeMB AS bigint) + ' * 1024 * 1024 '  

print (@Query)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a query string instead of using the variable in an actual query?

Answer (score 2):

Wht you do not calculate the `@MaxSizeMB x 1024 x 1024` out of the query and just concat the result to your query as below:

```
declare @MaxSizeMB BIGINT
set @MaxSizeMB = 50*1024*1024

DECLARE @Query varchar(8000)='' 

set @Query=            
'Update SPMC
Set SPMC.HasBlockedSize = 1, SPMC.HasIssues = 1
FROM PWI
INNER JOIN SI on SI.Id = PWI.SourceItemId
INNER JOIN SPMC on SPMC.SourceItemId = SI.Id
AND SI.ItemSize > '+ cast(@MaxSizeMB as varchar(max)) 

print (@Query)
```

You can also achieve the same result without using the dynamic SQL too. as follow:

```
Update SPMC
Set SPMC.HasBlockedSize = 1, SPMC.HasIssues = 1
FROM PWI
INNER JOIN SI on SI.Id = PWI.SourceItemId
INNER JOIN SPMC on SPMC.SourceItemId = SI.Id
AND SI.ItemSize > (@MaxSizeMB *1024*1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `MaxSizeMB` is already `BIGINT` converting it to `BIGINT` will have no effect, You should to convert the calculated value to `varchar(max)`.

```
declare @MaxSizeMB BIGINT
set @MaxSizeMB = 50

DECLARE @Query varchar(8000)='' 

set @Query=            
'Update SPMC
Set SPMC.HasBlockedSize = 1, SPMC.HasIssues = 1
FROM PWI
INNER JOIN SI on SI.Id = PWI.SourceItemId
INNER JOIN SPMC on SPMC.SourceItemId = SI.Id
AND SI.ItemSize > '+ cast(@MaxSizeMB * 1024 * 1024 as varchar(max))

print (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 declare @MaxSizeMB BIGINT
set @MaxSizeMB = 50
DECLARE @Query varchar(8000)='' 

set @Query=            
'Update SPMC
Set SPMC.HasBlockedSize = 1, SPMC.HasIssues = 1
FROM PWI
INNER JOIN SI on SI.Id = PWI.SourceItemId
INNER JOIN SPMC on SPMC.SourceItemId = SI.Id
AND SI.ItemSize > '+ cast(cast(@MaxSizeMB as bigint) as varchar(max)) +' * 1024 * 1024 '  

print (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

cast `@MaxSizeMB` to VARCHAR as you want to generate a dynamic query:

```
declare @MaxSizeMB BIGINT
set @MaxSizeMB = 50

DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(8000)='' 

set @Query=            
'Update SPMC
Set SPMC.HasBlockedSize = 1, SPMC.HasIssues = 1
FROM PWI
INNER JOIN SI on SI.Id = PWI.SourceItemId
INNER JOIN SPMC on SPMC.SourceItemId = SI.Id
AND SI.ItemSize > '+ cast(@MaxSizeMB as varchar) +' * 1024 * 1024 '  

print (@Query)
```